# install_github() error for existing package

Tags: r, github, package

I just put a package on github but am having trouble installing it using install_github(). The package is at https://github.com/nancyorgan/mapcalc

I've tried

```
install_github(repo = "mapcalc", username = "nancyorgan")
install_github("nancyorgan/mapcalc")
install_github(repo = "mapcalc", username = getOptions("nancyorgan"))
```

but the error I get is 'unable to find a non-generic version of function "initialize"'

I have devtools installed. Is there just a syntactical error? My package works fine when I install it from a local directory on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You have your package as a sub directory of the github repository try:

```
devtools::install_github('nancyorgan/mapcalc/mapcalc')
```

this seemed to work for me althou I didnt try any of the package functionality.

Comment: It still didn't work for me. Do you think it might help if I deleted the repo and then put it back so that mapcalc isn't inside mapcalc?

Comment: Try clearing your workspace. Also what OS are you using?

Comment: No go :/ It's OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Can you print exactly what you typed in to R? Ah, the irony of not being able to run my own package. @rawr

Comment: Installing github repo mapcalc/master from nancyorgan
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/nancyorgan/mapcalc/archive/master.zip
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  unable to find a non-generic version of function "initialize"

Comment: Have you tried installing any other package from github. Try `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')` for example.

Comment: It works now! Hopefully it will still work when I fix the subdir issue. Enjoy calculating your mean arterial pressure...